# Application of dependent product

Tags: dependent-types

On the proof assistants StackExchange site, someone gave this example of a dependent product:

$$\prod_{i\in I}\sum_{j\in J_i}x_{ij}=\sum_{f\in\prod_iJ_i}\prod_{i\in I}x_{if(i)}$$

The dependent product is the $\prod_iJ_i$ bit, and just what role it plays in this case is mysterious to me.

It's a very short answer, and the above equation expresses "the rule for multiplying out brackets".
https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1114/628

I am trying to understand the RHS as a procedure for multiplying an expression such as
$(a + b + c)(d + e)(f + g + h)$

So, say this expression is represented as a two-dimensional array, with a, b, c on the first row, and so on. Then, the formula on the LHS sums each row and calculates the product of the results.

What does the RHS do, in terms of code?

Comment: For all possible ways of picking one term from each bracket, it multiplies the terms, and finally it adds everything together. This is not an answer because I don't see how it can be made clearer "in terms of code". I think the code for this is rather confusing.

Comment: Thanks. I guess "sum \$ map (product) \$ sequence [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]" comes close to that description, but it lacks the use of indices.

Comment: @Trebor I've tried to answer my own question—would be interesting to hear what you think of my Python translation of the procedure you described.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Trebor for explaining the procedure.

Here is Python code which uses explicit indexing in order to match the original expression. For simplicity it replaces the function `f` with an array-—so `f(i)` becomes `f[i]`.

In order to get the dependent product of the arrays of indices, I use `itertools.product()`, because actually computing the Cartesian product is not really in the scope of the question, and how it is calculated is not conceptually important.

```
import itertools

# (1 + 3)(7 + 9 + 1 + 3)(6 + 7)
terms = [
   [1, 3],
   [7, 9, 1, 3],
   [6, 7]
]

indices = []
for t in terms:
    indices.append(list(range(len(t))))
 
fs = itertools.product(*indices)

total = 0
for f in fs:
    intermediate = 1
    for i in range(len(terms)):
        intermediate *= terms[i][f[i]]
    total += intermediate
    
print(total)
```